# What is the point of decreasing the indent size?

Tags: java

On these screenshots, you can see the difference between indent size.
The first one it's the default Code Style provided by Idea:

[image]

And the second one it's a [Google Java Code Style](https://github.com/akulik512/intellij-settings-repository/blob/master/styleguide/intellij-java-google-style-v2.xml) (I renamed it a little but it's the same default file):

[image]

The second screen clearly shows that the indents a smaller in a half.

What's the point in reducing them? And the second question is, how can I undo this modification by modifying the file?

Comment: "how can I undo this modification by modifying the file?" - I've just looked at the file, and the very option is `INDENT_SIZE` with a value of 2... I strongly suspect that setting that to 4 (and maybe `TAB_SIZE`) will do what you want.

Comment: Ohh thank you. Forgive me for my carelessness and my level of English.  I did a lot of tries to find words 'tabulation' or 'space' in this document, but I found out about the 'indent' word only when I wrote a question. Unfortunately, I can't remove this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow long lines become shorter to make more free room on small screens.

Answer (score 0):

The original 4 spaces indentation was intentionally introduced with the design of java (whereas the indentation of C/C++ was normally less), for a better overview and in order to punish too much nesting of blocks, using more sub-methods. And indeed this indentation does not hurt.

Google's later Java code style is an actionistic *reform*, which such a huge player like Google can push.

For a regular indention of code of 4 indents it would save only 8 characters.
This has minor effect when also considering the length of field/variable/method names.

So I would call the Google style hubris, a mistake for a language which has strong conventions. Other languages have more variations, especially on placement of parentheses and on spacing.

But one should adapt to the convention of the one of both, that is used in the firm. Google's style did not generally replace the old style, even though Android is a huge part on Google's home turf.